# how defer statement works exactly

Tags: go

i try to learn golang and use effective go as lecture. I stuck on capital defer, look at the following code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trace(s string) string {
    fmt.Println("entering:", s)
    return s
}

func un(s string) {
    fmt.Println("leaving:", s)
}

func a() {
    defer un(trace("a"))
    fmt.Println("in a")
}

func b() {
    defer un(trace("b"))
    fmt.Println("in b")
    a()
}

func main() {
    b()
}
```

as output i've got

```
entering: b
in b
entering: a
in a
leaving: a
leaving: b
```

I know, that defer statement will be execute after return statement in the function. But here, why entering: b is the first output? I am expected in b as the fist output!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer:

> The arguments to the deferred function (which include the receiver if the function is a method) are evaluated when the defer executes, not when the call executes. Besides avoiding worries about variables changing values as the function executes, this means that a single deferred call site can defer multiple function executions.

So **argument** of defer function (trace("b") in your case) evaluates first

Comment: If you want to avoid that behaviour and evaluate trace("b") exactly when defer function executes, you should use closure without parameters: http://play.golang.org/p/fG2ghTp-8h

Comment: But why does trace("b") executes first? I really do not understand this. When you read this sentence The arguments to the deferred function (which include the receiver if the function is a method) are evaluated when the defer executes, then entering: b should comes after in b.

Comment: I think, i do not understand the control flow of defer function.

Comment: You can see trace("b") will be execute inside un(). And this un() function will be execute, before function return. So I expected, that trace function execute, when un() executed, it is like nested function execution.

Comment: un(string) is defer function, but trace("b") is a parameter of it. To avoid parameter's change before defer function actually executes, have to evaluate parameter in same time as defer function (defer statement) declared

Comment: so everything, that pass as a parameter to defer function, will be evaluate, before defer function execute?

Comment: Yes, all parameters will be evaluated when defer statement declared. On execute of defer function (before return) will called with that parameters

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trace(s string) string {
    fmt.Println("entering:", s)
    return s
}

func un(s string) {
    fmt.Println("leaving:", s)
}

func b() {
    defer un(trace("b"))
    fmt.Println("in b")
}

func main() {
    b()
}
```

Output:

```
entering: b
in b
leaving: b
```

Since "arguments to deferred functions are evaluated when the `defer` executes", the

```
defer un(trace("b"))
```

statement in function `b` is, using explicit scope, equivalent to

```
{
    unarg := trace("b")
    defer un(unarg)
}
```

Therefore, equivalently,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trace(s string) string {
    fmt.Println("entering:", s)
    return s
}

func un(s string) {
    fmt.Println("leaving:", s)
}

func b() {
    {
        unarg := trace("b")
        defer un(unarg)
    }
    fmt.Println("in b")
}

func main() {
    b()
}
```

Output:

```
entering: b
in b
leaving: b
```

Equivalently, for your complete example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trace(s string) string {
    fmt.Println("entering:", s)
    return s
}

func un(s string) {
    fmt.Println("leaving:", s)
}

func a() {
    {
        unarg := trace("a")
        defer un(unarg)
    }
    fmt.Println("in a")
}

func b() {
    {
        unarg := trace("b")
        defer un(unarg)
    }
    fmt.Println("in b")
    a()
}

func main() {
    b()
}
```

Output:

```
entering: b
in b
entering: a
in a
leaving: a
leaving: b
```